# Abstract Algebra. Stabilizers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, cyclic-groups

[image]

i understand parts (a) and (b) I'm trying to prove part (c)
This is what i have in mind so far. [image]

am i on the right track or am i wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your write ups could do with some formalizing and cleaning up; you are on the right track for your second inclusion. For the first inclusion, we take some permutation $\tau$ for which $\tau(TOP)=HAT$, and we must decompose it as 
$$
\tau=\sigma\rho,\rho\in Stab(TOP).
$$
To this hand, note that since $\sigma(TOP)=HAT$, we must have $\sigma^{-1}(HAT)=TOP$. Thus 
$$
\sigma^{-1}\tau(TOP)=\sigma^{-1}(HAT)=TOP,
$$
so $\sigma^{-1}\tau\in Stab(TOP)$. Can you finish from here?

Comment: okay, Im still not sure how to finish it from there.